# SQL - Remove user login from 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I created a `moveDB` login. 
Unfortunately, it binds to `dbo` user, like the below image 
[image]

How can I remove `moveDB` login but don't affect `dbo`?

I searched on Google and some guy said that need to change `dbowner`, I'm unfamiliar with SQL permission so I wonder if it affects to `dbo` when I use `change_dbowner`

Answer (score 7):

Sorry guys, I found the answer by myself. When creating those databases, they was created under `moveDB` login. So I change owner of those databases to `sa` or `other logins`. Then remove `moveDB` login.

```
-- Select database to apply new change
EXEC sp_changedbowner '[new_login]'
```

Then remove login

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'moveDB')
DROP LOGIN [moveDB]
GO
```

Comment: The proper way to change the database owner is with `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase to [new_login]`.

Comment: You can also do it in the UI by deselecting the mapping for the login and then dropping the login. ```EXEC sp_changedbowner``` is not required.

Comment: @sthames42 deselecting the user mapping in the login's properties tries to delete DBO, which cannot (or at least should not) be done. I just had the same problem with an application installer mapping DBO to the account of the user running the install (which I have to undo). You have to remap DBO to a different login manually.

Comment: @KeithS I remember having this problem last year, which is how I found this issue, and that's how I solved it. I didn't experience what your describing but I'll watch out for it, in the future.